# How I can create a module which can receive and send mails to Zimbra server

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, email, smtp

How I can create a module which can receive and send mails (filter spam mails) to the Zimbra server, which is the best program language for this task?

Comment: Pyhton can be good just because you can send a email, albeit a very simple one, in less the 20 lines of code.

Comment: I need it can receive mail also, not just send email

Comment: The same applies for reading emails. Would you like me to answer with some sample code?

Comment: I would be very appreciative if you could @Haveaniceday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will send a email:

```
import smtplib
import ssl

port = 465  # for ssl
smtp_server = 'email.com'  # if it is a gmail account, use stmp.gmail.com
sender_email = 'email@email.com'
receiver_email = 'other_email@email.com'
password = 'Password'  # sender password
subject = 'Python email test'
message = f"""From: {sender_email}
To: {receiver_email}
Subject: {subject}

This email was sent from python."""

context = ssl.create_default_context()
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_server, port, context=context) as server:
    server.login(sender_email, password)
    server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message)
```

This code will read the first email in the inbox:

```
import imaplib

server = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('email.com', 993)  # if it is gmail use imap.gmail.com

email = 'email@email.com'
password = 'Password'

server.login(email, password)

stat, count = server.select('Inbox')  # count is the number of emails in the selected folder
                                      # in this case the Inbox
stat, data = server.fetch(count[0], 'BODY[TEXT]')  # count[0] means the first email

print(data[0][1].decode('utf-8'))
```